# Infinite load on tomcat server webapp startup

Tags: java, tomcat, tooltwist

I encountered a weird error when I upgraded from ToolTwist 8.1 to ToolTwist 8.5.

The error is infinite load on tomcat server webapp startup.

I think there is no error on loading the configurations because I am seeing the Tooltwist Startup Commencing on the console which means the tooltwist libraries was already been initiated.

So here is the console log regarding the problem.

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Tooltwist Startup Commencing <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
>>>>>>   This is tooltwist.misc.LoadConfigsServlet.
>>>>>>   Obtaining env-entry for TOOLTWIST_HOME from JNDI (e.g. web.xml)
>>>>>>   * Found /projects/8.5/curia/site-conf
>>>>>>   Will reconfigure logback if config file found
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>>>>>>   * Looking for (local file: /projects/8.5/curia/site-conf/conf/logback.xml)
>>>>>>   * Found - reconfiguring logback.
>>>>>>   Loading filemap if it's not already loaded
>>>>>>   * Filemap loaded.
>>>>>>   Will log test messages immediately after the next line (debug, info, trace, warn, and error)
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> Tooltwist Startup Finished <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

2015-05-25 12:07:12,073 DEBUG t.m.LoadConfigsServlet -    test debug message.
2015-05-25 12:07:12,076 INFO  t.m.LoadConfigsServlet -    test info message.
2015-05-25 12:07:12,077 WARN  t.m.LoadConfigsServlet -    test warn message.
2015-05-25 12:07:12,077 ERROR t.m.LoadConfigsServlet -    test error message.
2015-05-25 12:07:12,078 DEBUG t.c.s.CloudmallInitServlet - >>>>>>   * Found /projects/8.5/curia/site-conf
2015-05-25 12:07:12,078 DEBUG t.c.s.CloudmallInitServlet - >>>>>>   Getting the access token from TEA.
2015-05-25 12:07:12,319 DEBUG t.w.WbdCache - Loading webdesign projects from: /projects/8.5/curia/webdesign/
2015-05-25 12:07:12,320 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Adding webdesign project noah-webdesign
2015-05-25 12:07:12,324 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Loading extension projects from: /projects/8.5/curia/
2015-05-25 12:07:12,324 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Adding extension project bootstrap-tooltwist
2015-05-25 12:07:12,324 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Adding extension project cloudmall
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 DEBUG t.w.WbdCache - Ignoring project (contains no directory named 'widgets'): /projects/8.5/curia/config_plugin
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 DEBUG t.w.WbdCache - Ignoring project (contains no directory named 'widgets'): /projects/8.5/curia/deployed-server
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 DEBUG t.w.WbdCache - Ignoring project (contains no directory named 'widgets'): /projects/8.5/curia/RemoteSystemsTempFiles
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 DEBUG t.w.WbdCache - Ignoring project (contains no directory named 'widgets'): /projects/8.5/curia/Servers
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 DEBUG t.w.WbdCache - Ignoring project (contains no directory named 'widgets'): /projects/8.5/curia/site-conf
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Adding extension project tooltwist
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Adding extension project ttsec-standaloneDesigner
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Adding extension project ttStd
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 DEBUG t.w.WbdCache - Ignoring project (contains no directory named 'widgets'): /projects/8.5/curia/ttsvr
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Adding extension project ttWbd
2015-05-25 12:07:12,325 DEBUG t.w.WbdCache - Ignoring project (contains no directory named 'widgets'): /projects/8.5/curia/webdesign
2015-05-25 12:07:12,328 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Registering interceptor: interceptor.multiTenantByUrl.xml
2015-05-25 12:07:12,343 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Registering interceptor: interceptor.multitenant.xml
2015-05-25 12:07:12,343 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Registering interceptor: interceptor.navpoint.xml
2015-05-25 12:07:12,362 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - Initializing interceptor (class=tooltwist.cloudmall.interceptors.NavpointInterceptor)
2015-05-25 12:07:12,362 DEBUG t.c.i.NavpointInterceptor - init() start...
2015-05-25 12:07:12,363 INFO  t.w.WbdCache - - interceptor registered.
2015-05-25 12:07:13,559 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> GetAccessTokenXDS - START
2015-05-25 12:07:13,705 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> GetAccessTokenXDS - END  | 147ms
2015-05-25 12:07:13,709 DEBUG t.c.b.c.ConverterHelper - Parsing:  to integer.
2015-05-25 12:07:13,714 DEBUG t.c.s.CloudmallInitServlet - >>>>>>   Setting the access token to redis.
2015-05-25 12:07:13,715 DEBUG t.c.b.ProjectToken - setAccessTokenToRedis() start...
2015-05-25 12:07:13,716 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> SetAccessTokenToRedisXDS - START
2015-05-25 12:07:13,721 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> SetAccessTokenToRedisXDS - END  | 5ms
2015-05-25 12:07:13,721 DEBUG t.c.s.CloudmallInitServlet - >>>>>>   Setting the hostname for server environment
2015-05-25 12:07:13,727 DEBUG t.c.s.CloudmallInitServlet - >>>>>>   Setting the category to redis.
2015-05-25 12:07:13,734 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> GetAccessTokenFromRedisXDS - START
2015-05-25 12:07:13,738 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> GetAccessTokenFromRedisXDS - END  | 4ms
2015-05-25 12:07:13,745 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> SetMenuCategoryListXDS - START
2015-05-25 12:07:13,796 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> SetMenuCategoryListXDS - END  | 51ms
2015-05-25 12:07:13,796 DEBUG t.c.s.CloudmallInitServlet - >>>>>>   Setting the catalogue to redis.
2015-05-25 12:07:13,801 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> SetMenuCatalogueListXDS - START
2015-05-25 12:07:13,808 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> SetMenuCatalogueListXDS - END  | 7ms
2015-05-25 12:07:13,809 DEBUG t.c.s.CloudmallInitServlet - >>>>>>   Setting the tenant to redis.
2015-05-25 12:07:13,810 DEBUG t.c.b.TenantMisc - setTenantToRedis() start...
2015-05-25 12:07:13,811 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> SetTenantToRedisXDS - START
2015-05-25 12:07:13,817 DEBUG t.c.x.BaseXDS - =====> SetTenantToRedisXDS - END  | 6ms
May 25, 2015 12:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/ttsvr] is completed
May 25, 2015 12:07:23 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader modified
INFO:     Additional JARs have been added
May 25, 2015 12:07:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/ttsvr] has started
May 25, 2015 12:07:23 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/ttsvr] appears to have started a thread named [java-sdk-http-connection-reaper] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

TIA

Comment: Please post the content of the log in text format, not as an image. There's a message in the SEVERE log that states there's a memory leak but we cannot see more of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think so that there's no error on your code/configuration, did you tried to check the proper configuration for your server.xml and web.xml?

also, on your server.xml, kindly check if the **reloadable** on the **Context** tag is set to false. This will stop the catalina to continuously check for changes and prevent it from reloading the webapps again. I think the problem lies in there.

[Here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html) is the link for the documentation